# Current and voltage from PV ( LTS25NP , LV 25-P)

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, sensor, solar-cell

So in my design I am going to sense two PV panels in series ( Both voltage and current) to extract the Maximum power point (MPPT by arduino) so the input of both sensors will be the PV output and the output of the sensors will be input to arduino uno.

My question is how should I connect these sensors

- [LTS25NP](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/729438619_2/LEM-LTS25-NP-Hall-Current-Sensor.jpg)
- [LV 25-P](http://www.dacpol.eu/files/en/katalog/ed15/2/226_228/7-8.jpg)

Comment: What do the datasheets say ?

Answer (score 1):

The LTS25 claims to be a Hall sensor - if so it MAY be suitable for DC from your panel.
It's diagram show an internal transformer - this may not be what is actually there. If it is then it is unsuitable for DC.  Odds are it is unsuitable. 
Links to a site with more details would help us help you better.

As shown the diagram is completely clear - use it as per spec sheet. If you follow it it should work as long as it is made for DC, which does not appear likely :-(.

---

The LV series sensor that you show APPEARS to be suited for DC but more specs would help.
I could suggest connections etc but you telling us more would be the best you can do.

---

What are the circumstances of you having THESE sensors?
Why do you think they are suitable?
What are the panel specs - this matters immensely.
Voc, Isc,Vmp, Imp[, Wmp, ... ?
Those are very standard terms  - if you do not know them or are not able to find out about them for your panels then MPPT will be a difficult goal. 
Student project / private project / ???